# Returns to Scale off a figure

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, input-output

This is the table given for levels of output for different levels of inputs.

\begin{pmatrix}
Q  & K & L\\
100 & 3  & 6\\
200 & 5 & 10\\
300 & 7.5 & 15 \\
400 & 10 & 20 \\
500 & 12.5 & 25 \\
600 & 15 & 30
\end{pmatrix}

These are questions on my Final review guide and I am getting different answers than my professor and feel like he may be wrong. Here are the questions.

1) Which of the following conclusions can be drawn from this information?

- A)Increasing returns to scale exist between 100 and 200 units of output.

  - B) Constant returns to scale exist throughout all levels of production.
- C) Labor is subject to diminishing marginal productivity in the short run.
- D) No firm conclusions can be drawn.

2)Returns to scale are greatest at which level of output?

- A) 100-200 units
- B) 200-400 units
- C) 400-600 units
- D) There is insufficient information to answer the question.

3) At which level of input are there constant returns to scale?

- A) 400-600 units
- B) Constant returns to scale exist throughout all levels of production.
- C) Constant returns to scale do not exist at any level of production.
- D) No firm conclusions can be drawn.

The Answers I concluded were 1) D, 2) C, and 3) C

I can give you my professor's answers if need be. But if what you guys respond with is the same as what my professor has then I will contact him.

Comment: Do you know how to determine increasing, constant, and decreasing returns to scale in general?

Comment: Yes I do, at first, it made it hard because there is no equation but after looking at it farther I understand now why I am wrong.